# Usar um ResultSet em java pra imprimir na tela toda uma tabela qualquer

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset

sei que com o resultSet podemos fazer várias coisas com um SELECT feito em alguma tabela. POr exemplo: sei que podemos pegar uma tabela e imprimir o seu conteúdo, listando quais colunas queremos com métodos como: getString e getInt.

```
Conection con = ........
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Clientes");

while(rs.next()) {

  String nome = rs.getString("Nome");
  System.out.println("Nome do Cliente: " + nome);
}
```

Mas se eu quero simplesmente mostrar todo o conteúdo de qualquer tabela que eu receba por parâmetro, nãos servem esses métodos. Teria que ter algo do tipo:

```
System.out.println (rs.getAll());
```

Ou seja, eu quero um método que pegue o resultado do meu SELECT * e mostre na tela, independente de quais ou quantas colunas tem na tabela.

Exsite na ResultSet isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não existe, mas o `ResultSet` possui métodos que permitem criar tal funcionalidade. Exemplo:

```
public class ResultSetExibirTabela {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        //Coloque as informações de conexão do seu banco
        Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection("url","meuUsuario", "minhaSenha");

        //Entre com o nome da sua tabela
        exibirTabela(conexao, "nomeDaTabela");

        conexao.close();
    }

    public static void exibirTabela(Connection conexao, String nomeDaTabela) throws SQLException {
        ResultSet rs = conexao.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + nomeDaTabela).executeQuery();

        ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
        int numeroDeColunas = metaData.getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(", ", "[", "]");
            for (int coluna = 1; coluna <= numeroDeColunas; coluna++) {
                String nomeDaColuna = metaData.getColumnName(coluna);
                joiner.add(nomeDaColuna + "=" + rs.getObject(coluna));
            }
            System.out.println(joiner.toString());
        }

        rs.close();
    }
}
```

Numa tabela chamada "Pessoa", com as colunas de nome "id", "nome" e "observacao", a saída poderia ser algo semelhante a isso:

```
[id=1, nome=Pessoa 1, observacao=Esta é a Pessoa 1]
[id=2, nome=Pessoa 2, observacao=Esta é a Pessoa 2]
[id=3, nome=Pessoa 3, observacao=Esta é a Pessoa 3]
```

Comment: :O Excelente. Não conhecia alguns tipos que tu usaste aí. Ajudou bastante. Obrigado!

Comment: Mais uma coisa: Esse método "prepareStatement()" nã é usado somente quando, no nosso sistema, temos a característica de executar muitas vezes o mesmo "statement? Em outros casos poderíamos usar direto um Statement st;                                                                                                      st.executeQuery(); ??  Qual é a a melhor prática?

Comment: Felipe Marinho: um problema com usar o StringJoiner, é que ele simplesmente coloca uma string do lado da outra. O que gera ua tabela desalinhada, dependendo de quantos caracteres tem cada item da tabela:                                                                                                     [ID = 1,NOME = Programador,NIVEL = tecnico]
[ID = 2,NOME = Analista de Sistemas,NIVEL = tecnico]
[ID = 5,NOME = Testador,NIVEL = tecnico]
[ID = 6,NOME = Testadora,NIVEL = tecnico]

Comment: @LucasPletsch Sobre o `PreparedStatement`: além deste benefício que você citou, ele também ajudar a impedir *SQL Injection* se usado corretamente. Nesse exemplo que dei, o uso dele não é necessário, pode-se utilizar um simples `Statement`. Quanto ao `StringJoiner`: ele apenas junta as *Strings* com os delimitadores, o prefixo e o sufixo informados. Caso você queira uma formatação mais elaborada (que exiba os dados como uma tabela), você precisa verificar qual é o valor mais longo de cada coluna para definir o tamanho mínimo dela.

Comment: Sobre o StringJoiner: exato. Sò não descobri ainda como editar a largura da "coluna".kkk

Comment: @LucasPletsch Suponha que a `String` chamada `maior` seja a maior `String` da coluna, e que `s` seja qualquer outra `String` dessa coluna. Para você editar a "largura" basta fazer `int v = (maior.length() - s.length()) / 2`. Agora é só adicionar `v`  espaços em branco antes e depois de `s` (caso `maior.length() - s.length()` seja ímpar, você terá que adicionar um espaço a mais antes ou depois de `s`).