# COmo formatar a impressão de resultSet via System.out.println no Java?

Tags: java, sql, resultset

Olá, estou imprimindo na tela o resultado de um SELECT que armazenei num objeto tipo resultSet (sql.ResultSet). Mas sai "tudo torto". Tentei usar o "\t" entre cada coluna impressa, mas não adiantou. Segue abaixo o trecho do método que nos interessa:

```
public void selectCargos(String query){

            try {
                rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                System.out.printf("TABELA DE CARGOS\n\n");
                while (rs.next()){
                    System.out.println("ID: " +rs.getInt("id")+ "\t"+ "Nome do cargo: " +rs.getString("nome")+ "\t" + "Nível do cargo: " +rs.getString("nivel"));
```

Comment: PS: esse problema só existe se eu tenho apenas um tipo de tabela que eu desejo imprimir. Em um caso da vida real, em que minha aplicação terá muitas classes "entidade", com suas respectivas tabelas, o ideal é que utilizemos um método genérico de impressão de tabelas, como o que tem nesse tópico aqui:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272747/usar-um-resultset-em-java-pra-imprimir-na-tela-toda-uma-tabela-qualquer/272798#272798

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while ( rs.next() ) {
       System.out.println( " ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + "\n Nome do cargo: " + rs.getString("nome")  + "\n Nível do cargo: " + rs.getString("nivel") );
    }
```

**Pode imprimir desa forma:**

```
  System.out.println("##############################################"); 
  System.out.println(" ID: " + rs.getInt("id") );
  System.out.println(" Nome do cargo: " + rs.getString("nome") );
  System.out.println(" Nível do cargo: " + rs.getString("nivel") );
  System.out.println("##############################################");
```

**ou**

Você pode sobrescrever o `toString()` se você tiver usando um objeto.

```
    public String toString() {
      return "ID: " + rs.getInt("id") + "\n Nome do cargo: " + rs.getString("nome") + "\n Nível do cargo: " + rs.getString("nivel");
    }
```

Comment: LR10, entendi. Sim, essa tabela é do objeto Cargo. Basta eu implementar o to string nessa classe, exatamente como você fez? Ou eu tenho que salvar esses dados na tabela na forma de um objeto "Cargo"?

Comment: você está buscando do banco e imprimindo via system.ou.*; pode passar via construtor e depois imprimir usando toString.

Comment: Entendi. valeu!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma formatação tipo C, usando System.out.format:

```
String ID = "10"; //rs.getInt("id");
String nomeCargo = "Analista de Sistemas"; //rs.getString("nome");
String nivelCargo = "Senior"; //rs.getString("nivel");
System.out.format("ID: %-4s Nome do cargo: %-50s Nível do cargo: %s", ID , nomeCargo, nivelCargo);
```

O sinal negativo é para alinhar à esquerda e o número é uma quantidade fixa de casas para sua string (assim fica igual a uma tabela). Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/yl8rqq).

Comment: Não conhecia esse método "format" também. Boa dica. Valeu!